# Вопрос \ ответ Telegram.Bot C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Разрабатываю бота цель которого собрать информацию о пользователе, суть такова бот задаёт вопрос "Ваше Имя" после ответа пользователя бот должен зать следующий вопрос "Сколько Вам лет" опять ждёт ответа пользователя и после задаёт следующий вопрос. Не до конца понимаю реализацию данного действия.
У меня бот выпуливает из списка всё что можно:

```
   if(messageText == "1️⃣ - Акт согласования" || messageText == "1")
    {
       

        Message questionN_1 = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
        chatId: chatId,
        text: ConnectBotDB()[0],
        replyMarkup: replyMenuKeyboardMarkup,
        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        
        if (questionN_1.Text == ConnectBotDB()[0])
        {
            Message questionN_2 = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
            chatId: chatId,
            text: ConnectBotDB()[1],
            replyMarkup: replyMenuKeyboardMarkup,
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }

        

    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста или поделитесь примером реализации данного действия. Возможно нужно сравнивать `questionN_1` и `messageText` ? Но тогда я буду натыкаться на то что `MessageText` никогда не будет `null`. Спасибо большое всем за идеи и подсказки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - это отвечать на сообщения бота. Т.е. бот отправляет какое-то сообщение и предлагает пользователю ответить на это сообщение, и если пользователь ответит на это сообщение, то бот поймет, на какой вопрос ответил пользователь

```
        if (update.Message.Text.ToLower() == "/start")
        {
            await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: update.Message.Chat.Id, text: "Ваше имя", replyMarkup: new ForceReplyMarkup { Selective = true });
            return;
        }
        if (update.Message.ReplyToMessage != null && message.ReplyToMessage.Text.Contains("Ваше имя"))
        {
            //записываете куда-либо введенное имя
            await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: update.Message.Chat.Id, text: "Сколько вам лет", replyMarkup: new ForceReplyMarkup { Selective = true });
            return;
        }
        if (update.Message.ReplyToMessage != null && message.ReplyToMessage.Text.Contains("Сколько вам лет"))
        {
            //ваша дальнейшая обработка
        }
```